# I am trying to display text and multiple emoji from unicode in tetxview dynamically

Tags: android, string, unicode, emoji

I have try already to convert unicode to emoji but at a time only one emoji set. i want display in textview multiple emoji .
my problem is i want to display text with multiple emoji on textview dynamically.

for example : String str = "Happy" + unicode + "Birthday" + unicode + "ComingSoon" + unicode + "Dear" + unicode + unicode;

according to above string i want display multiple emoji with text on textview.

private static String escapeNonAscii(String str) {

```
StringBuilder mStr = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    int cp = Character.codePointAt(str, i);
    int charCount = Character.charCount(cp);
    if (charCount > 1) {
        i += charCount - 1; // 2.
        if (i >= str.length()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("truncated unexpectedly");
        }
    }

    if (cp < 128) {
        mStr .appendCodePoint(cp);
    } else {
        mStr .append(String.format("\\u%x", cp));
    }
}
return mStr.toString();
```

with above code noot display emojis...

Comment: show me what is your problem show the sort of code that you have problem

Comment: Hi @janvi! Welcome to stack overflow. Your question doesn't clearly define what it is that you wish to ask. Please edit your question to include the code of what you have already tried and what it is that you are having problems with.

Comment: sir plzz help me